# Returning values from a database with a Substring

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Let's say I've got 3 product description fields with the values AC-120 XXX, AC-120,CCC and AC-120 BBB.

How would I get that information from a table using only AC-120 as my search argument?

I've tried using the subStr function but that won't return any values either

```
    SELECT TbArtikel.Artikel_Merk, TbArtikel.Artikel_Groep, TbArtikel.Artikel_Categorie_ID, TussenMAATenARTKEL.VoorraadNummer, TbArtikel.Artikel_ID, TussenMAATenARTKEL.ArtikelDetail_ID, TbArtikel.Artikel_Prijs_Advies, TbArtikel.Artikel_Prijs_Bees, TbArtikel.Artikel_Omschrijving
FROM TbArtikel INNER JOIN TussenMAATenARTKEL ON TbArtikel.Artikel_ID = TussenMAATenARTKEL.Artikel_ID
WHERE (((TbArtikel.Artikel_Merk)="Yonex") AND  ((TbArtikel.Artikel_Omschrijving)="%AC-102%"));
```

Comment: _"I've tried using the subStr function"_ Share your code please.

Comment: Use `MID()` function as `SELECT MID(YourColumn, 1, 6)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIKE` is *very* appropriate for this comparison.  However, MS Access uses different wildcards from standard SQL.  So you want:

```
TbArtikel.Artikel_Omschrijving) LIKE "*AC-102*"
```

In standard SQL, this would be:

```
TbArtikel.Artikel_Omschrijving) LIKE "%AC-102%"
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Try '((TbArtikel.Artikel_Omschrijving) LIKE "%AC-102%"' instead of '((TbArtikel.Artikel_Omschrijving)="%AC-102%"'

Comment: What if `'AC-102'` is in the end of the string?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp according to this site "%subString%  Finds any values that have "subString" in any position"

Comment: Using LIKE "%AC-102%" did not work, it wouldn't display any information

Comment: This property has to be used on the where field, it should work, cause this is the way to do properly

Answer (score 0):

Use `MID()` function as

```
MID(TbArtikel.Artikel_Omschrijving, 1, 6) = 'AC-120'
```

Instead of

```
TbArtikel.Artikel_Omschrijving ="%AC-102%"
```